# How to convert nested array to a flat array?

Tags: arrays, scala

I have a nested array:
`Array("AA", Array("BB", "CC"), "DD")`. How can I convert it into:
`Array("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD")` in Scala?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Thanks for all answers! I really appreciate them. I noticed that I made a mistake. My data actually looks as follows: Array((AA, Array(BB, CC), DD)). The example answer given below (arr.flatMap) would cause type mismatch. Sorry I am new to Scala. It looks like an array of tuple which contains a nested array. In this case, I still want the format: Array((AA, BB, CC, DD)). Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

First of all check out the inferred type of the array:

```
scala> val arr = Array("AA", Array("BB", "CC"), "DD")
arr: Array[java.io.Serializable] = Array(AA, Array(BB, CC), DD)
```

Scala's collections have a single type for their elements, so if you put both a string and an array of strings (or an array of an array of strings) in an array, you'll end up with an array with an element type that's the most specific type shared by both `String` and `Array[String]`—in this case `Serializable`, which is pretty useless, since to do anything with the elements of the array you'll have to cast them to some other type.

So it's best not to get yourself into this situation in the first place. You'll get much more mileage out of the type system if you don't mix unrelated things in collections. That said, if you absolutely have to do this, you can write something like the following:

```
def flattenStringArrays[A](arr: Array[A]): Array[String] =
  arr.flatMap {
    case s: String => Array(s)
    case a: Array[_] => flattenStringArrays(a)
  }
```

And then:

```
scala> flattenStringArrays(arr)
res0: Array[String] = Array(AA, BB, CC, DD)
```

Or if you "know" you'll only ever have one level of nesting:

```
scala> arr.flatMap {
     |   case s: String => Array(s)
     |   case a: Array[String] => a
     | }
res1: Array[String] = Array(AA, BB, CC, DD)
```

But both of these are unsafe and really unidiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

```
array.flatMap {
    case x: Array[_] => x
    case y => List(y)
}
```

Comment: Uh, I already gave this exact solution (but without the confusing mixing of `List` and `Array`).

Comment: This is not a perfect solution but definitely not as bad as -1 would mean. A proper solution would be without the `List`

Comment: @TravisBrown, I didn't read your answer before answering, it works, it's short, to downvote it just because you wrote something similar is not very nice, it's not a race.

Comment: @MatiasSaarinen It is not perfect, and will not work with two level deep nestings.

Comment: Nothing personal—I downvote any code-only answers I notice, and in this case in particular there's a lot of context that's needed for a useful answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my version using foldLeft and some pattern matching: (It does not preserve the original order)

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_79).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>   val container = Array("AA", Array("BB", "CC"), "DD")
container: Array[java.io.Serializable] = Array(AA, Array(BB, CC), DD)

scala>   container.foldLeft(Array.empty[String]) { (memo, next) =>
     |     next match {
     |       case s: String => s +: memo
     |       case arr: Array[_] => arr.map(_.toString) ++ memo
     |     }
     |   }
res0: Array[String] = Array(DD, BB, CC, AA)
```